# How do I unit test jdbc code in java?

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, jdbc, junit

I'd like to write some unit tests for some code that connects to a database, runs one or more queries, and then processes the results.
(Without actually using a database)

Another developer here wrote our own DataSource, Connection, Statement, PreparedStatement, and ResultSet implementation that will return the corresponding objects based on an xml configuration file. (we could use the bogus datasource and just run tests against the result sets it returns).

Are we reinventing the wheel here? Does something like this exist already for unit testing?
Are there other / better ways to test jdbc code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) together with a [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) which can read its initial data from CSV files for example.

Comment: Can you provide any examples? I am looking for examples but can't find any that is easy to follow.. I am using maven.

Answer (score 33):

You have several options:

- Mock the database with a Mock library, e.g. [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/). The huge drawback of this that your queries and the data will most likely be not tested at all.
- Use a light weight database for the tests, such as [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). If your queries are simple, this is probably the easiest way to go.
- Dedicate a database for the tests. [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) is a good option, or if you are using Maven, you can also use the [sql-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/) to set up and tear down the database properly (be careful of dependencies between tests). I recommend this option as it will give you the biggest confidence that the queries work properly with your db vendor.

Sometimes it is necessary and useful to make these tests configurable so that these tests are only executed if the database is available. This can be done with e.g. build properties.

Comment: Thanks I like the idea of using maven to setup / tear down the database. We're using maven now for builds so this would be pretty easy for us to use.

Comment: The DBUnit link (http://www.dbunit.org/) takes to a chinese website which may have nothing to do with DBUnit.

Comment: @user3885927 I fixed the link. The next time you spot such a thing, feel free to submit an edit to fix the broken link.

Answer (score 8):

I like to use a combination of:

- [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)
- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)
- [Unitils](http://unitils.org) (specifically, the [database testing](http://unitils.org/tutorial-database.html) and [maintenance modules](http://unitils.org/tutorial-dbmaintain.html))

You can get pretty far with just DBUnit and HSQLDB. Unitils provides the last mile of code to manage and reset database state. It also provides a nice way of managing database schema changes and makes it easy to use specific RBDMS (Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, etc). Finally, Unitils provides some nice wrappers around DBUnit which modernizes the API and makes DBUnit much more pleasant to work with.

If you haven't checked out Unitils yet, you definitely should. Unitils is often overlooked and under-appreciated.

Comment: This is the stack I tend to use as well.  DBUnit/H2/Unitils

Answer (score 4):

That's why you have [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (now called JavaDB) or [sqlite](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) -- they are small, simple databases that you can create, load, test against and destroy relatively quickly and simply.

Comment: But any code that depends on vendor-specific SQL that isn't supported by the lightweight db will not be testable.

Comment: @Asaph: "vendor-specific SQL" is often a mistake.  However, when you go to test vendor-specific SQL, you're not doing unit testing, so that's not really a unit test issue, is it?

Comment: It's more of an integration test than a unit test at that point. But connecting to MySQL in a JUnit test is arguably not fundamentally different from connecting to sqlite from a JUnit test. I see both scenarios as integration tests. What would truly make it a _unit_ test would be having mocks or fakes at all the database seams, ie. no database server (lightweight or heavyweight) at all. Having said that, I'm not fanatic about adhering to this principle _all_ the time. As long as the tests run fast and don't require lots of manual setup, it's okay with me.

Comment: @Asaph: Mocking the database -- while technically possible -- is usually silly.  You don't write it, therefore you must *trust* it.  If you don't trust it, stop considering it, and find something you do trust.  Since you trust it, use it for testing.  You trust your test framework.  (You don't test it, do you?) You trust your compilers and libraries.  It's okay to trust a JDBC service, too.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that HSQL is the way to go during your unit tests. The point of your test is to test your jdbc code and make sure it works. Adding custom classes or mocking the jdbc calls can easily hide bugs.

I mostly use mysql and when the tests run the driver class and url is changed to org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver and jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) for testing a *not-so-easy-to-test code*.

Answer (score 2):

Acolyte driver can be used to mock up a JDBC connection, managing it during tests and returning data as result set (with its typesafe row list API): https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte

Note: I am the author of Acolyte.

Comment: Can you go through these https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=user%3A3347384+is%3Aa+acolyte&mixed=0 and check them for self disclosure please. If you can reply here when you're done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do unit tests, not an integration tests, than
you can use a very basic and simple approach, using Mockito only, like this:

```
public class JDBCLowLevelTest {

    private TestedClass tested;
    private Connection connection;
    private static Driver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        // (Optional) Print DriverManager logs to system out
        DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter((System.out)));

        // (Optional) Sometimes you need to get rid of a driver (e.g JDBC-ODBC Bridge)
        Driver configuredDriver = DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:odbc:url");

        System.out.println("De-registering the configured driver: " + configuredDriver);
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(configuredDriver);

        // Register the mocked driver
        driver = mock(Driver.class);
        System.out.println("Registering the mock driver: " + driver);
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Let's cleanup the global state
        System.out.println("De-registering the mock driver: " + driver);
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // given
        tested = new TestedClass();

        connection = mock(Connection.class);

        given(driver.acceptsURL(anyString())).willReturn(true);
        given(driver.connect(anyString(), Matchers.<Properties>any()))
                .willReturn(connection);

        given(connection.prepareCall(anyString())).willReturn(statement);        
    }
}
```

Than you can test various scenarios, like in any other Mockito test e.g.

```
@Test
public void shouldHandleDoubleException() throws Exception {
    // given
    SomeData someData = new SomeData();

    given(connection.prepareCall(anyString()))
            .willThrow(new SQLException("Prepare call"));
    willThrow(new SQLException("Close exception")).given(connection).close();

    // when
    SomeResponse response = testClass.someMethod(someData);

    // then
    assertThat(response, is(SOME_ERROR));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/).  It won't allow you to test your jdbc code without a database, but it seems like you could introduce a different set of buys by emulating a database.

Answer (score 1):

While the way to mock jdbc in your application is of course dependant on how you've implemented your actual jdbc transactions.

If you're using jdbc as is, I'd assume you have written yourself an utility class of sorts to do some tasks in the line of `DBUtils.getMetadataFor(String tablename)`. What this would mean is that you'd have to create a mock of that class and that could be all you need. This would be rather easy solution for you since you apparently already have a series of jdbc related mock objects available. Note that I'm assuming your jdbc code isn't exploded all around the application - if it is, refactor!!!

If you're however using any framework for database handling (like Spring Framework's JDBC Template classes) you can and should mock the interface class using EasyMock or some other equivalent. That way you can have all the power in the world required for easy mocking of the connection.

And last if nothing else works, you can do what others have said already and use DBUnit and/or derby.

Answer (score 0):

We use Mockrunner. http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/  It has mock connections and datasources built in so there is no need to implement them your selves.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JDBDT: http://jdbdt.org

You can use it for database setup and assertions, as an alternative to DBUnit.

Note: I am the author of JDBDT.