# Proper Unit Testing in void method in java without mocking

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

Is there a way to test a method that doesn't return any value without the use of Mockito?
This is the sample method. I'm new in Unit Testing.

```
public void addMantisData(ArrayList<Mantis> list) {

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mantises (ticketId, startDate, endDate, hours, minutes, " +
                        "employeeId, timeIn, timeOut, dateSubmitted, category, status, timestamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");

        for (Mantis mantis : list) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, mantis.getTicketId());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, mantis.getStartDate());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, mantis.getEndDate());
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, mantis.getHours());
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, mantis.getMinutes());
            preparedStatement.setInt(6, mantis.getEmployeeId());
            preparedStatement.setString(7, mantis.getStartTime());
            preparedStatement.setString(8, mantis.getEndTime());
            preparedStatement.setString(9, mantis.getDateSubmitted());
            preparedStatement.setString(10, mantis.getCategory());
            preparedStatement.setString(11, mantis.getStatus());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }

        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        preparedStatement.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I apprieciate the help :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? If that's the building of the query then you can consider taking it to a separate method and test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems more like it would be an integration test with the DB then a pure unit test. Also im not sure what it is that you want to test, if it is the query you will need to perform the insert and then try to get expected values from the DB and `assert` with expected result. Make sure that you use your own instance of the DB and also rollback after the test. [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) will make this happen for you, check it out

Comment: I see. So If I continue to test this method it is more of a Integration Testing rather than just a Unit Test.
I'm currently given some excerise to improve my software testing skills. The test I'm developing right now is for the TAD developers in preapration to our actual project.

Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any "mock" or "spy" classes (hand-made or from Mockito), you could consider a "cheap" database that lives in-memory (or backed by temporary files). Then your code can issue queries via JDBC just like the real thing, and your unit test can prepare data and inspect results (also via JDBC).

Be sure to read the [answers for this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/how-do-i-unit-test-jdbc-code-in-java).