# JUnit testing SQL queries

Tags: java, sql, testing, junit

I'm working on a project and we are required to create some test cases. I have a SQL database and parsing data there with queries like:

```
public Contractor create(String name, String address, String email, String phone, String city, int cvr) throws SQLException{
    Contractor contractor = new Contractor(name, address, email, phone, city, cvr);
    String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO person (name, address, email, phone, city, category) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', 2)", name, address, email, phone, city);
    try{
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getInstance().getDBcon();
        conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);

        String sql2 = "SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Person ORDER BY id DESC";
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql2);

        if(rs.next()) {
            String sql3 = "INSERT INTO contractor (cvr, person_id) VALUES (2666,"+rs.getInt("id")+")";
            conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql3);
        }else{
            throw new SQLException();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DBConnection.closeConnection();
    }
    return contractor;
}
```

How would the test with JUnits look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/how-do-i-unit-test-jdbc-code-in-java

Comment: I'm asking about JUnit, I have seen this theard and it didnt help me. But thank you.

Comment: The link @Darshan posted should be helpful. Also learn about PreparedStatements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the way Junit must be used is by *testing each public method of your class*, with as many different parametrizations as the number of experiments can success or fail.

Each testing method, then, must:

- Chose a proper set of parameter values.
- (Optionally) Initialize the tested component in a required initial state.
- Invoke the tested method.
- Check that the returned result is equal to the expected result.
- Clean up the tested component not to let any "dirt" from the executed test.

In your case, there is a difficult checking the results, because the connection is managed locally by your method. Even worse: The data is committed automatically into the connection, leaving dirty records in the database on each test.

To avoid this difficult, it would be enough with a little previous refactoring to ease the test development:

- Overload in your class the method `create`, with a package-access version which recieves also a Connection, and put there all the business logic.
- The public overload should only manage the connection and call the newly created overload.

Then, you can make your test safely:

- If your class is named `MyClass`, create a `MyClassTest` in the same package (typically in a different source path, like `src\test\java` in a Maven project).
- Create a method `createSinglePerson()` which invokes `create` with an arbitrary set of parameters and one connection (not auto-commit). After that, you must check that there is one record more than initially in the *Person* table, with a certain set of values, and one more record in the *Contractor* table with a certain set of values. To compare each value you must use `Asserts.assertEquals(expected, real)`. At the end (in a finally clause), do a rollback to the connection and close it.

You can run your test as many times as needed, knowing that it won't alter the database state.

(Note: Parameter `cvr` is never used. Maybe you did it on purpose, I don't know).

### Example

```
public class MyClassTest
{
    @Test
    public void createSinglePerson()
    {
        MyClass myClass=new MyClass();
        try(Connection connection=...)
        {
            try(Statement stCheck=connection.createStatement())
            {
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);

                // Initial cleanup:
                stCheck.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM person");
                stCheck.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM contractor");

                // Setting input parameters:
                String name="a";
                String address="b";
                String email="c@d.e";
                String phone="001";
                String city="f";
                int cvr=11;

                // Do the call:
                Contractor contractor=myClass.create(name, address, email, phone, city, cvr);

                // Javabean Checks: Check the javabean contains the expected values:
                assertEquals(name, contractor.getName());
                assertEquals(address, contractor.getAddress());
                ...

                // Database Checks:
                int personId;
                // Check the Person table contains one row with the expected values:
                try(ResultSet rs=stCheck.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person"))
                {
                    assertTrue(rs.next());
                    personId=rs.getInt("id");
                    asssertEquals(name, rs.getString("name"));
                    asssertEquals(address, rs.getString("address"));
                    ...
                    assertFalse(rs.next());
                }

                // Check the Contractor table contains one row with the expected values:
                try(ResultSet rs=stCheck.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contractor WHERE person_id="+personId))
                {
                    assertTrue(rs.next());
                    asssertEquals(2666, rs.getInt("cvr"));
                    ...
                    assertFalse(rs.next());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                 // Undo the testing operations:
                 connection.rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            fail(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. I'm quite new to java could you please show me some real example? I have tried according to this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html but with no luck.

Comment: I would like to ask you. If I do initial cleanup of tables as you showed me and then call rollback will i keep my old files in database?

Comment: You should. But, in fact, there is a risk that if your tester program halts unexpectedly before normal end, the rollback will not get performed, and then the data will be losed. To prevent this disaster, it is worth using a separate DB for testing. You could use an in-memory database, like Derby or HSQLDB.

Comment: Or, well, there is also another choice: The purpose of cleaning up the data is to ease looking up the newly created record in Person table. If you modify the testing logic, you could look it up by another criteria (for example, getting the last record inserted) without the need for an initial cleanup.