# How to catch SQL syntax errors from a .properties file?

Tags: java, sql, ide

I need to edit upwards of 100+ queries stored in .properties for a Java app. I currently use Notepad++ to open up and edit the queries before practicing running them. This workflow is not working out because Notepad++ even with SQL language selected doesn't alert me about missing (), missing commas, or a missing \ at the end.

The queries are formatted initially as:

```
supply_items=select item,date,sum(case when (color='orange' or color='red') then 0 else 1) /
from table /
where year = ? and /
month = ?
```

I copy paste it out into PGAdmin and run it as a SQL query that will pass compilation:

```
select item,date,sum(case when (color='orange' or color='red') then 0 else 1) 
from table 
where year = '2019' and 
month = 'January
```

Then I edit it for the data fix and correspondingly edit the .properties file.

The problem I'm encountering is I'll make small syntactical mistakes at the point where I copy back in the good query and reformat it. For instance, I'll copy this back in:

```
supply_items=select item,date,sum(case when (color='orange' or color='red') / then 0 else 2 
from table /
where year = ? /
month = ?
```

There is a / at the wrong place in line 1, a missing ) at line 2, and a missing and at line 4. But a readthru doesn't catch it for me when I'm editing 100+ at a time.

I'm on a data team, so the dev team is responsible for building and testing. I would build and test on my own, as that would easily point me to the issues, but my team is against that idea. I've thought about writing a script to pass in all the queries and test for syntactical correctness, but I wouldn't be sure where to get started (eg. a common library for reading .properties queries this way). I'm also open to an IDE that would be able to highlight errors from a .properties ruleset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I **unit test** jdbc code in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266370/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

I gave this issue some more thinking and came up with two solutions:

1. Write a script that reads and "unit tests" the queries in the .properties file. I did this in python for fast setup, with pyjavaproperties. sqlite already had an API solution to pass in paramters to queries with ?'s, so I used that.
2. Use git diff. I realized that if I committed the new queries that were all but syntactically correct, diff would alert me to format changes (or at least areas where there could be format changes, and I could see the original to compare). Git bash isn't well suited for this so I chose diffmerge as my UI.