# How to implement Junit testing for Insert operation using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, crud

I am totally 0 in JUnit also I am completely new to Java, here is the code for Insert operation in MySQL using JDBC,

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class InsertPStatementExample {
    private static final String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO newUsers" +
        "  (name, email, country, password) VALUES " +
        " (?, ?, ?, ?);";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {
        InsertPStatementExample createTableExample = new InsertPStatementExample();
        createTableExample.insertRecord();
    }

    public void insertRecord() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(INSERT_USERS_SQL);
        // Step 1: Establishing a Connection
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_database", "root", "root");

            // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            
//          preparedStatement.setInt(1,autoGeneratedID);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "steve");
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "steve@gmail.com");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "AUS");
            preparedStatement.setString(4, "simple");

            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet tableKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            tableKeys.next();
            int autoGeneratedID = tableKeys.getInt(1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            // print SQL exception information
            printSQLException(e);
        }

        // Step 4: try-with-resource statement will auto close the connection.
    }

    public static void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {
        for (Throwable e: ex) {
            if (e instanceof SQLException) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
                System.err.println("Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
                System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
                Throwable t = ex.getCause();
                while (t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine, but I need to implement JUnit testing for the insert operation for my given task, which I don't know how to do.

Can anyone help me on this to implement it?

Comment: While unit testing are you going to use any in-memory storage or else your MYSQL?

Comment: @Sibin, could you please elaborate on it?, sorry to ask, but I am a newbie to this

Comment: While unit testing you should never use your real database(mysql), you should mock your data with the help of in-memory databases. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/how-do-i-unit-test-jdbc-code-in-java

Comment: So do I need to do this process in a separate class? and how can I test them If I need to check the insert values, how to do them in the test file?

Comment: 1. Your unit test compatible code should be a separate class.
2. Unit tests should be in a separate class.
3. Configure in-memory database

Comment: @Sibin Not true, with testcontainers-java, you can test against your actual RDBMS if you want, and it is better than testing against a different in-memory system that has a different syntax and different quirks than your actual target RDBMS.

Comment: And the most important thing is @Madan explored more out of the box today. Maybe he would answer this question below.

Comment: "Basically, Testcontainers would provide a disposable(in-memory) stand-in database. So, no extra configuration is needed." https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/